# Running a Windows app from tomcat service doesn't show the window

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

I am trying to run a Windows app (a window with UI and sounds). I've changed Tomcat service to be opened using the same windows user as the one that logged in to the machine.
When I run this, the app is started, I can even hear it sounds, but no window is visible.
How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of windows are you running?

Comment: I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Well, as all other found out, I didn't really need to run it as server, but as the user logged in... Thanks